# Disabling IIS url Scanner

Tags: iis

I have found [here](http://www.pressthered.com/rejected-by-urlscan_404_errors/)  how I can remove the module - but I will still need this module in the future. 
Is there some way I can disable it temporarily and then enable when I need it? Or to temporarily "allow anything"?

Thanks

Comment: I am surprised that this tool is still being used. it was quite useful with IIS5 in the early century....

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault kneidels! You may want to add some more background to your question with some keywords that help people find it, e.g. server version, OS, etc.